# how to write a code that will stop a Jframe's action until another Jframe's button is not pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working with two Jframes AFrame and BFrame.In Aframe there is a register button if the button is pressed then it will open B-frame. Now I want to stop Aframe's action until Bframe's Submit button is not pressed.

Here is my code of Aframe.

```java
if (e.getSource() == Register) {  
    BFrame BF=new VerificationFrame();
    BF.setVisible(true);
    if(BF.Submit.getModel().isPressed()){
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
}
```

Here is code of my Bframe.

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==Submit){
        String Ucode=Codef.getText();
        getUcode(Ucode);
    }
}
```

I want is when I will press the register button it will wait until the Bfrane's submit button is not pressed. If the submit button is pressed it print "yes" but every time I run this code it doesn't work.

Comment: An application should NOT have multiple JFrames. It should only contain a single JFrame. Then if you need another window you can use a modal JDialog. A modal JDialog will prevent you from clicking on the parent JFrame until the dialog is closed. Or maybe in your case you can use a simple JOptionPane to get a single piece of data. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for example of using a JOptionPane.

Comment: Yes, i know. Jdialog will prevent my problem. But i was trying to my own dialog. Thanks for the swing tutorial link.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of ways to achieve that.

i. Disable button in A in the method running for A, enable it back in the B registration method.

ii. Use a boolean variable that is true when b is pressed and false when A is pressed.

Comment: if you are free. will  you please write a code what you have told me ??

Comment: If you are interested in solving this, will you please show some effort? SO is not a code generation service.

Comment: Yeah i have solved it.but not in your way :) Thank you tho. :)